# How to get table Name , Raw countOfTheDay,Job status, job start and end date time

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL job that run on a daily basis to process the data from staging table to Warehouse table .There are a lot of steps and a lot of staging tables. I need the below information

Desire output-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBQ8s.png)

I have tried the below query but this query is not providing the desire output

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put attempts in the comments; it is not helpful. Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're still yet to [edit] your question.